# Difference in the way of representation of timestamp in the provided dataset and the one generated by pandas.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I was having trouble manipulating a time-series data provided to me for a project. The data contains the number of flight bookings made on a website per second in a duration of 30 minutes. Here is a part of the column containing the timestamp

```
>>> df['Date_time']

 0     7/14/2017 2:14:14 PM           
 1     7/14/2017 2:14:37 PM           
 2     7/14/2017 2:14:38 PM
```

I wanted to do

```
>>> pd.set_index('Date_time')
```

and use the datetime and timedelta methods provided by pandas to generate the timestamp to be used as index to access and modify any value in any cell.
Something like

```
>>> td=datetime(year=2017,month=7,day=14,hour=2,minute=14,second=36)
>>> td1=dt.timedelta(minutes=1,seconds=58)
>>> ti1=td1+td
>>> df.at[ti1,'column_name']=65000
```

But the timestamp generated is of the form

```
>>> print(ti1)
2017-07-14 02:16:34
```

Which cannot be directly used as an index in my case as can be clearly seen. **Is there a workaround for the above case without writing additional methods myself?**

I want to do the above as it provides me greater level of control over the data than looking for the default numerical index for each row I want to update and hence will prove more efficient accordig to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the dtype of the 'Date_time' column and confirm for me that it is string (object) ?

```
df.dtypes
```

If so, you should be able to cast the values to pd.Timestamp by using the following.

```
df['timestamp'] = df['Date_time'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

When we call .dtypes now, we should have a 'timestamp' field of type datetime64[ns], which allows us to use builtin pandas methods more easily.

I would suggest it is prudent to index the dataframe by the timestamp too, achieved by setting the index equal to that column.

```
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
```

We should now be able to use some more useful methods such as

```
df.loc[timestamp_to_check, :]
df.loc[start_time_stamp : end_timestamp, : ]
df.asof(timestamp_to_check)
```

to lookup values from the DataFrame based upon passing a datetime.datetime / pd.Timestamp / np.datetime64 into the above. Note that you will need to cast any string (object) 'lookups' to one of the above types in order to make use of the above correctly.

I prefer to use pd.Timestamp() - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html to handle datetime conversion from strings unless I am explicitly certain of what format the datetime string is always going to be in.

Comment: when I tried using df['Date_time'].dtypes i got "dtype('O')", that is a python object, so I used type(df['Date_time'].iat[1]) which gave me "<type 'unicode'>".

Comment: Yes, so the df['Date_time'] column is a string - in pandas dtypes, str comes out as object - however, when you've accessed a value of the column directly using type it's given you unicode (string). Pandas is good at string manipulation, but you are certainly encouraged to work with 'better' types as often as possible. If a Timestamp, use a Timestamp, if a float, use a float etc etc. Casting to correct types can earn huge speedups and advantages.